# Python error in update dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am having some issue in my code. In a loop a try to update one python dictionary.

```
    print('INICIAL>>>',ref,':',subpart_actual,'\n\n')
    components.update({ref:subpart_actual})
print('FINAL>>', components)
```

The output of this is:

```
INICIAL>>> Voltages11 : {'footprint': 'Project:TerminalBlock_Philmore_TB13x_04x5mm_Straight', 'reference': 'P', 'manf#': '1757268', 'value': '4 vias terminal', 'digikey#_subqty': '1', 'manf#_subqty': '1', 'digikey#': '277-1108-ND', 'libpart': 'aquisitionCape-cache:CONN_01X04'} 

INICIAL>>> Voltages12 : {'footprint': 'Project:TerminalBlock_Philmore_TB13x_04x5mm_Straight', 'reference': 'P', 'manf#': 'OSTTJ047150', 'value': '4 vias terminal', 'digikey#_subqty': '1', 'manf#_subqty': '1', 'digikey#': 'ED2781-ND', 'libpart': 'aquisitionCape-cache:CONN_01X04'} 

FINAL>> {'Voltages11': {'footprint': 'Project:TerminalBlock_Philmore_TB13x_04x5mm_Straight', 'reference': 'P', 'manf#': 'OSTTJ047150', 'value': '4 vias terminal', 'digikey#_subqty': '1', 'manf#_subqty': '1', 'digikey#': 'ED2781-ND', 'libpart': 'aquisitionCape-cache:CONN_01X04'},
         'Voltages12': {'footprint': 'Project:TerminalBlock_Philmore_TB13x_04x5mm_Straight', 'reference': 'P', 'manf#': 'OSTTJ047150', 'value': '4 vias terminal', 'digikey#_subqty': '1', 'manf#_subqty': '1', 'digikey#': 'ED2781-ND', 'libpart': 'aquisitionCape-cache:CONN_01X04'} }
```

The last update appear to overwrite the all subfields of my dict, even that ones that are not equal ('manf#" and 'digikey#').

Is it a wrong way to use `my_dict.update()`?

Comment: No, what's wrong is how you're creating `subpart_actual`. You're probably retaining the reference and overwriting its values.

Comment: An _extremely_ quick fix would involve `components.update({ref:subpart_actual.copy()})` -- creating a shallow copy, but it doesn't solve the root problem which is your misunderstanding of how copies work. We can't help you with that without your code.

Comment: Thanks. This solved. :-D